# GCM ANDROID not able to send Notification/message to android device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get gcm notification in my android mobile.my device gets registered and also i can unregistered it ,in browser it shows device registered but when i click send message to device it gives me 500 error, i am running it on Apache the error is following

```
     java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
 java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
 java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
 java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
 java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
 java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
 com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:550)
 com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
 sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
 sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
 sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
 sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:271)
 sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:328)
        sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:778)
sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:881)
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:479)
com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:458)
com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:170)
com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:82)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Please help me out..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 is server error , this may due to the wrong format of http post to the google server or there will be network problem, check your post method various parameter. for more information

```
         http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html
```

Comment: checked everything but still getting the same error.i know there is simple mistake that i couldn't find it.